# How do i have the scores in my text file arranged by average?

Tags: python, sorting

I have created the code for 3 scores to be taken from the text file and sort the names 
alphabetically but I'm struggling to know how to sort the scored highest to lowest by average

```
#Opens up the text file "class1.txt"
            class1 = open('class1.txt', "r")
#Reads the lines in class as' results file
            classread = class1.readlines()
#Alerts the user that the names in class1.txt will be sorted alphabetically
            print("Names sorted alphabetically")
            print()
            print("Name           Last 3 scores")
            print()
#Sorts the list alphabetically
            for word in sorted(classread):
                word = word.rstrip()
                print(word)
                class1.close()
```

Comment: You need a key function. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 1):

The function `sorted` can receive a keyword argument called `key`, which is a function that returns a comparable argument for each element of the list.

If you have two lists with the names in in one and the averages in the other, you could use:

```
indexes = sorted(range(len(names)), key=lambda i: averages[i])
sortedNames = [names[i] for i in indexes]
```

If you have a dictionary in the form `name: average` you could use:

```
sortedNames = sorted(nameDict.keys(), key=lambda name: nameDict[name])
```